# BroadcastReceiver not called when intent has setComponent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a simple `MyBroadcastReceiver`. I try to send a broadcast:

```
    ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
            MyBroadcastReceiver.class.getPackage().getName(),
            MyBroadcastReceiver.class.getName());
    intent.setComponent(name);
    intent.setAction(Constants.RECEIVER_ACTION);
    mContext.sendBroadcast(intent)
```

My receiver is registered inside a `onResume`:

```
    if (mReceiver == null) {
        mReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    }
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Constants.RECEIVER_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

If I comment `intent.setComponent(name)` it gets called. Am I setting the component name wrong?

Comment: How you initialize your `intent`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what that does mean.

Comment: No problem. Would you show us also your `IntentFilter`? The conflict there are `component name` and `action`.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the value of `Constants.RECEIVER_ACTION` ? :)

Comment: `com.example.mypackage.ReceiverAction`